# How to get pivot table entry using row and column's index in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I want to access pivot table entries through row and column number. How can I get the value that corresponds to row = 1 (userID = 2110) and column = 1 (ISBN = 0001046438)? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: `df.loc[2110, '0001046438']`? You may need to change `2110` to `'2110'` as well.

Comment: for evaluation, can you post the text data for this DataFrame as to_csv, or to_dict